# Bitmap OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, html, parsing

I have question about this error.

I make favicon parser from URLs. I do this like:

```
public class GrabIconsFromWebPage {
public static String replaceUrl(String url) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("https?://.+\\..+?\\/");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
    while (m.find()) {
        sb.append(m.group());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static String getFavicon(String url) throws IOException {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Element element = doc.head().select("link[href~=.*\\.(ico|png)]").first();
        if (element != null) {
            if (element.attr("href").substring(0, 2).contains("//")) {
                return "http:" + element.attr("href");
            } else if (element.attr("href").substring(0, 4).contains("http")) {
                return element.attr("href");
            } else {
                return replaceUrl(url) + element.attr("href");
            }
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch(OutOfMemoryError er) {
        er.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

and how I get bitmap from url

```
Bitmap faviconBitmap = GrabIconsFromWebPage.getBitmapFromURL(
                                GrabIconsFromWebPage.getFavicon(
                                        bookmarkData.get(position).getUrl() // url from which I want to grab favicon
                                )
                        );
```

And this code after uploading 20 images give me OutOfMemoryError. How can I fix this? Or optimize? Cuz in my list where I show this icons, can be more than 20 or 40 favicons...

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run?

Comment: Could you please tell us the following: 1) memory allocated 2) what are you doing doing with the URL's that you are fetching?

Comment: @MJSG, 1.  standard amount of memory, 2. I gave it to the parser and he get favicons if found them. I posted more details code

Comment: What do you do with the Bitmap object created, is it stored in memory? If yes, then that is most probably your culprit.

Comment: @KevinWorkman, yes maybe, if it'll help

Comment: @MJSG, I show it in the list with title... I do not know whether he has retained in memory

Comment: If you do not know, then you are not. Have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: @Pztar, I have get OutOfMemoryError, not OutofMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget.

Comment: @dajver, it's a generic message. Look at the lessons available, it will show you how to properly load the bitmaps. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: We cannot see what you do with the constructed Bitmap's. Any reason you want to make huge Bitmaps from small icons? Please give an example url of such an icon that we can download and ispect too.

Comment: @Pztar, But favicons aren't large, they are small, something like 10x10 px or smaller. Or I don't understans something?

Comment: @greenapps, http://developer.android.com/favicon.ico, and there are 50 favicons like this in the app from other pages.

Comment: Ok. But why would you make Bitmap's out of them. Please explain.

Comment: `after uploading 20 images` ?? I thought you were downlloading them.from those url's. Is there anymore that you did not tell?

Comment: hmm, sorry, I download favicons from some urls which user add to my app. It's can be any of other urls with favicon. And I parse link and found favicon there. And after this I show them in my list near title.

Comment: And why are you making Bitmaps out of them? THIRD REQUEST!

Comment: @greenapps, what I should do out of them? I don't understand ,what do you mean?

Comment: I did not say -yet- what you should make out of them. I asked you three times why you make Bitmaps out of them. What is the reason for that?

Comment: I have to show them in imageview, how can I show them there, if they are not birmap?

Comment: To show them THERE you prabably have to make Bitmaps of them THERE. But not HERE or during transport from HERE to THERE. Please tell a bit more how you collect all and  transport them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was bad idea with parsing icons by myself. Google did it before us

http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=(domain)

Answer (score 1):

I think, you would use [universal image loader](http:////%20Load%20image,%20decode%20it%20to%20Bitmap%20and%20return%20Bitmap%20synchronously%20ImageSize%20targetSize%20=%20new%20ImageSize(80,%2050);%20//%20result%20Bitmap%20will%20be%20fit%20to%20this%20size%20Bitmap%20bmp%20=%20imageLoader.loadImageSync(imageUri,%20targetSize,%20options);)

The method as given snippet

```
// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and return Bitmap synchronously 
ImageSize targetSize = new ImageSize(80, 50); 
// result Bitmap will be fit to this size
Bitmap bmp = imageLoader.loadImageSync(imageUri, targetSize, options);
```

And for out of memory bound you would add a line in manifest file

```
<application
        ...
        android:largeHeap="true"
        ...
        >
</application>
```

Comment: largeHeap should NOT be used just because you've run out of memory. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#CheckHowMuchMemory

Comment: Ya, it dipped on your application, and level of image processing you  require.

Comment: It's helped) But applications loaded after start more than 2 minutes)

Comment: Ok, you may also try other options in universal image loader.